# Firefox Addon SDK CustomEvent details changed

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am writing a FF Addon using the Addon SDK (for FF42), I am passing a Custom Event as so

```
var item = {'details123': $obj};
console.log(item);
var e = new CustomEvent("deets", item);
window.dispatchEvent(e);
```

and am listening as so

```
window.addEventListener("deets", function($obj){
    console.log("obj received?");
    console.log($obj);
});
```

However, `$obj` gets overwritten to `isTrusted:false`. Could someone please help me figure out why this is happening?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to docs about [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) you must create it passing it an object with a `detail` attribute in the first level, this way:

```
var obj = {detail: {a: 1, b: 2}};
var e = new CustomEvent("myevent", obj);
```

Then, the event listener has to access that detail attribute:

```
window.addEventListener("myevent", function(evt){ console.log("obj=" + JSON.stringify(evt.detail)); });
```

[image]